# Borders of <p> element don't show up as block element in Ipad/Pro device

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

When I make the browser in Ipad / Ipad pro state the purple borders of

element doesn't show up. Why?

Relevant code:

```
<img src="RotateMobile.gif" alt="" id="rotateAnimation">
    <p id="rotateText">Please turn your device</p>
```

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    @media screen and (orientation:portrait)
    {

        #rotateAnimation {
            width: 80vw;
            height: 60vh;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 30vh;
        }

        #rotateText {
            font-size: 300%;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
            border-top: 3vh solid #D52C82;
            border-bottom: 3vh solid #D52C82;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
vs
[image]

Comment: You need to ask your question better - as far as I can tell, the borders are indeed showing in iPad mode rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionaly add left:0; and right:0; on rotateText,

```
#rotateText {
       left:0;
       right:0;
    }
```

Comment: Worked, but why ? i thaught you can use only right or only left